# update panel stops working in IE 8 when site is redirected via a proxy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, browser, internet-explorer-8

the site normally works fine in all popular browsers including firefox, chrome, safari and ie.

but doesn't work in ie 8 when it's redirected via a proxy server and it gives an error saying

"Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '
DOCTYPE html PUB'."

this only happens if (in ie 8) && (via a proxy server)

any idea??

Answer (score 1):

Its because the UpdatePanel expects its Response formatted a specific way("|" delimited).  If anything tampers with the format of the data in transit, it cannot parse the response.

[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException - what it is and how to avoid it](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)

> Asynchronous postbacks go through the
>   same life cycles events as regular
>   pages (this is a question I get asked
>   often). Only at the render phase do
>   things get different. We capture the
>   rendering of only the UpdatePanels
>   that we care about and send it down to
>   the client using a special format. In
>   addition, we send out some other
>   pieces of information, such as the
>   page title, hidden form values, the
>   form action URL, and lists of scripts.

Comment: Yes, but the site works fine in all browsers.
it has this error only in IE8 and using proxy server. the proxy server add a 0- prefix in the url. so the site url is normally www.abc.net and proxy server add 0-www.abc.net.do.net, any idea?
:<